# Looping over a list and get new variables

Tags: r, list, loops

I am total newby to R and want to apply a specific function to a list of data.frames.
The dataframes contain rows completely filled with 0 and I want to delete them from my dataframe.

Sample dataframe:
| OTU ID | Sample 1 | Sample 2 | Sample 3 | Sample 4 |
| :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- |
| abc | 12 | 24 | 0 | 120 |
| bcd | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| efg | 12 | 24 | 0 | 120 |
| hij | 24 | 9 | 13 | 4 |

For one table the code would be as follows:

#' in column 1 are the rownames, so the rowSums-function should be applied to all columns besides column 1

```
all_zero <- rowSums(table1[,-1]) == 0
```

#' then the rows that include only 0 should be deleted from the data.frame

```
table1 <- filter(table1, !all_zero)
```

As I have 10 different data.frames on which I want to apply the function, I want to create a for-loop or lapply()

#' first I created a list of the data.frames

```
all_df <- mget(ls([1:10])
```

and then I get stuck. Maybe you can help me finalize the options

a) for-loop (Here maybe it is silly to create so many new variables, better to get out a list?)

```
for (df in all_df) {
  paste0("no_reads_", df) <- rowSums(df[,-1]) == 0
  paste0(names(all_df), "_neu") <- filter(df, !paste0("no_reads_", df))
}
```

b) lapply (Here I don't know how to include best the second step of the command)

```
lapply(seq_along(all_df),
       function(df) rowSums(all_df[,-1][[df]]) == 0)
```

You would help me a lot :)
Best,
Kathrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using a for loop:**

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in seq_along(df_list)){
  df_list[[i]] <- df_list[[i]] %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(sum = sum(c_across(-"OTU_ID")) %>%
    filter(sum > 0)
}
```

**Using `purrr::map()`**

```
df_list %>%
  map(~ rowwise(.x) %>%
        mutate(sum = sum(c_across(-"OTU ID"))) %>%
        filter(sum > 0))
```

Comment: With the for-loop,rowwise gives an error because it includes the first column ("OTU ID") which is type character. The other columns are numeric.

Comment: oh ok, that wasn't clear from your question. You can insert a `select(-"OTU ID")` before `rowwise()`. Let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: Perfect, that solved my problem very quickly :)

Comment: ah, in the output, the OTU ID - Column should be included and with this command it is excluded. It should only be excluded in calculating the sum. Can we include something that includes rowwise(besides column 1)? Sorry for the problems..

Comment: it's difficult for me to debug without you providing a sample dataset, but try the edit that i just posted

Comment: i added a sample dataframe, because the solution you recommended did not work. Is this now more comprehensible?

Comment: Please use `dput(head(data, 5)` to make a sample dataframe. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sooo, I think it works if you delete the everything